What am I doing wrong when using attributedLabel in Flutter Semantics?
I am trying to use SpellOutStringAttribute to spell out the attributedLabel, but it just doesn't spell it.
The documentation says:

A string attribute that causes the assistive technologies, e.g. VoiceOver, to spell out the string character by character.

I am using a physical Android device with TalkBack to try it.
I couldn't find a working example.
Semantics(
    attributedLabel: AttributedString(
      'something',
      attributes: <SpellOutStringAttribute>[
        SpellOutStringAttribute(
          range: const TextRange(
            start: 0,
            end: 4,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.$red,
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ),
  ),

